# Multiple Entries Return Lowest Data With Lowest Date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

We had a few spreadsheets get imported multiple times into a database so we now have duplicate data (which of course had primary keys etc been assigned this would not have happed...)

However - the issue at hand is I need a way to return the data associated with the smallest (oldest) date for each `PN` in the database.  Below is a sample of the data and the structure.  I tried to use `Top 1` but I realized there was no rhyme or reason to what SSMS deemed as the 1st entry.

What would a query be for the syntax below to return the oldest date - expected returned results:

> Number One 111111   2014-01-01
>     Number Two 2222     2014-02-22

Sample DDL ->

```
  Declare @Test Table (pn varchar(200), ECN int, d1 date)
  Insert Into @Test (pn, ECN, d1) Values
  ('Number One', '111111', '2014-01-01')
  ,('Number One', '111111', '2014-01-31')
  ,('Number One', '111111', '2014-02-14')
  ,('Number Two', '2222', '2014-02-22')
  ,('Number Two', '2222', '2014-02-25')
```

Comment: [HS] please, don't delete your question when people make answer, that's rude. BTW, here is something that should make you understand group by http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cca27a/1

Comment: @Blag - Sincerest apology.  Thank you for that sqlfiddle that does help clear things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT pn, MIN(d1) AS [oldestDate]
FROM @Test
GROUP BY pn


pn          oldestDate
Number One  2014-01-01
Number Two  2014-02-22
```